# In C, what is the limit for program return values? Or, what is causing this?

Tags: c, echo, return-value

Came across this curiosity:

```
int main() {
  ...
  return 9000;
}
```

`~$ ./a.out || echo $?` yields `40`.

Hmm, maybe '40' is exit status for a number too high?

Change `return 9000` to `return 41`--echoes 41.

How about `100`? That echoes too. How about `1000`? That echoes `231`--hmm, so 40 must not be the exit status for a number too high.

Try `232`--echoes 232.

Suffice it to say, I suddenly find myself curious about the limits for return values in C programs. Anyone have any information on this? [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#C_language) provides some common information, but it doesn't explain the above behavior.

Comment: 9000 % 256 == 40...

Comment: Okay. Can you explain more? 1 % 256 != 1...

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks, couldn't find that in my searches.

Comment: A quick look at the bash manpage says that an exit status cannot be over 255.